# How to tell compiler that this variable is not a primitive value?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I want to declare that my function's args are object.

```
function foo(obj1: object, obj2: object){
  obj1.name = 'foo'
  obj2[MAYBE_ANY_PROPERTIES] = 'bar'
}
```

But when I try to compile, tsc tell that `Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'`.

I understand this error, but anyway, I want to tell compiler that  `obj1` is an object which may have any properties, but it should never be a primitive value. How can I do?

Comment: Simply write: <any>obj1.name=‘foo’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the object to be indexable, you need a `string` index. You can use the `Record` type to get that effect:

```
function foo(obj1: Record<string, any>, obj2: Record<string, any>){
  obj1.name = 'foo'
}

foo(1, 2) //err
foo("", "") // err

foo({ name: "" }, { name: "" }) // ok
```

You might consider a stricter type if your objects must contain a specific property:

```
function foo(obj1: {name: string } & Record<string, any>, obj2: {name: string } & Record<string, any>) {
  obj1.name = 'foo'
}

foo({ name: "" }, { name_: "" }) // error no name
```